# Transactions not persisting - Spring MVC with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC (4.1.6) app, using Hibernate ORM (5.3.7) on top of a MySQL 8 Database.

I have a view with a form that should create a row in the DB when it is submitted, but it does not. I can tell the information gets to my @Service bean and DAO @Repository bean. I can also successfully query data from the DB and display it on a view, if I update the DB directly through SQL.

I have read a number of posts and tried to reconfigure my application context and servlet context XMLs with no luck. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Below are some snippets.

**Web_XML**

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-dao.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-web.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

**applicationContext-web.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="edu.neu.snowfinder">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean class= "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>
```

**applicationContext-dao.xml**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource"/>
        <property name = "configLocation">
            <value> classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id = "transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref = "dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userHibernateDAO")
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void createUser(User user) {
        System.out.println("Does the Sevice have the user?"+user.getFirstname());
        userDAO.createUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Collection<User> listUsers() {
        return userDAO.listUsers();
    }

}
```

**UserHibernateDAO**

```
@Repository
public class UserHibernateDAO implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void createUser(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Does the DAO have the user?"+user.getFirstname());
        System.out.println("Does the DAO have a session?"+sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().toString());
        Serializable id = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Whats the saved User's ID??"+id.toString());

    }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name = "hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name = "hibernate.showsql">true</property>
        <property name = "hibernate.formatsql">true</property>
        <property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class = "edu.neu.snowfinder.model.User"/>
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Don't do `session.beginTransaction` and commit that is what `@Transactional` is doing for you. Also your `include` filter is pretty useless as it still scans everything, it doesn't exclude anything. Add `use-default-filters=false` to the `context:component-scan` in your `application-web.xml`. Finally include your `hibernate.cfg.xml` in your question.

Comment: When I add use-default-filters=false and restart the server, I get a resource not found error.

Comment: Don't add additional information as comments, edit your question. You should only add `use-default-filters=false` and leave the include.

Comment: Also remove the transaction management from your DAO, spring handles that.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I moved my comment into the post as you suggested. 

To make sure I understand, you are suggesting to remove the beginTransaction()/Comitt() lines from my UserHibernateDAO? And for the <context: items, remove the `<context:component-scan/>`, keep the `<context:include-filter/>` and `use-default-filters=false`?

Comment: No you still need the `context-componet-scan` but need to add `use-default-filters=false`. And yes remove the transactional stuff as Spring takes care of that. If this leads to errors it means your configuration is wrong.

Comment: The issue ended up being with the security policies on my localhost that was running MySQL server. I ended up getting 2003 error _Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection_ that indicates the connection was refused. [link]https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

I ended up abandoning MySQL and converting everything over to HSQL [link]http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/06/using-hypersql-hsqldb.html which worked for my purposes